# Dynamic Table in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Is it possible to make a model that uses a different table dependent on an association.

Comment: It think you'd get a better answer if you provided some more details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: http://guides.rails.info/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Comment: Can you give an idea of what it is you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The question is not very clear.... anyway you should consider rethinking about your classes structure and using "polymorphic associations" (if needed):

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association